# Cannot debug user javascript in WKWebView using safari's web inspector

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, safari, wkwebview

I add my jsScript to WKWebView as following:

`WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKUserScript *userScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptSource...];
[configuration.userContentController addUserScript:userScript];`

I am sure my script have ran successfully. But I cannot find my script using Safari's Web Inspector. I remember I have saw my added scripts appeared as 'User Script' in Web Inspector weeks ago. I don't know why it doesn't work right now.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of some error in my new jsscript. When i fix it, it disappears on web inspector.